# Making primary key same as foreign key in Hibernate entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am new to Hibernate. I am working on two entities as follows:

**Entity 1 is as follows:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vm_user")
public class VmUser implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "last_modified_by")
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private Instant createdDate;

    @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
    private Instant lastModifiedDate;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    private User user;             <--- HOW WILL I DENOTE THIS PRIMARY KEY OF VMUSER ENTITY ?
```

In the associated table in mysql i.e. `vm_user`, `user_id` is both primary key as well as foreign key which refers to id of `user` table associated with `User` entity.

**Entity 2 is as follows:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "last_modified_by")
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private Instant createdDate;

    @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
    private Instant lastModifiedDate;

    @ManyToOne
    private A a;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    private B b;
```

In the associated table in mysql i.e. `my_entity`, primary key is a combination of `id of a` and `id of b`. I am not getting how to denote this in Hibernate entity `MyEntity`.

Regarding the same, I have gone through a few posts: [Hibernate foreign key as part of primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146671/hibernate-foreign-key-as-part-of-primary-key) and [JPA & Hibernate - Composite primary key with foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58527109/jpa-hibernate-composite-primary-key-with-foreign-key), but no getting idea how to do these two ?

Comment: show your user entity also.. is user primary key int or string?

Comment: @GolamMazidSajib, id is a primary key of type integer of user table associated with User hibernate entity.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is `@MapsId`

For example

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vm_user")
public class VmUser implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")    
    private Integer id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    private User user;
```

You can also remove the `@JoinColumn(unique = true)` because `@Id` makes it unique already.

```
public class MyEntityPk implements Serializable {

   private Integer aId;
   private Integer bId;

   // IMPORTANT: Override equals() and hashCode()
}


@IdClass(MyEntityPk.class)
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Integer aId;
    @Id
    private Integer bId;

    @MapsId("aId")
    @ManyToOne
    private A a;

    @MapsId("bId")
    @OneToOne
    private B b;
```

Please find more information in the Hibernate documentation https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived

Comment: you declare id as primary key,  i think OP want to make user_id as primiary key

Comment: I added the ColumnMapping

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Would you please suggest an approach for entity 2 as well ?

Comment: I add the solution for second entity as well. Important is that the PK class must implement Serializable and override equals and hashCode

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Yeah. One small doubt in your solution. Don't you have to add any mapping like which id the attribute mapping to ? I mean here we have two Ids annotations and two MapIds annotations. So how would it figure out aId corresponds to A or B, same for bId ? Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `@EmbeddedId` and `@MapsId` ,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vm_user")
public class VmUser implements Serializable {
   @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")    
    private Integer id;

    @MapsId("user_id")
    @OneToOne
    private User user;  
}
```

You can do the same thing for MyEntity as below,

```
@Embeddable
class BKey {
  private int aId;
  private int bId;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private BKey primaryKey;

    @MapsId("aId")
    @ManyToOne
    private A a;

    @MapsId("bId")
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    private B b;
}
```

Comment: @code-mode I don't have any vm_user column. So I guess vm_user column to be omitted from your answer. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

And also, regarding entity 2, would you please suggest an approach ?

Comment: Add id for `vm_user` ,  `vm_user_id`. You can do the same thing for `MyEntity`

Comment: @code-mode, for vm_user table user_id is the primary key.

Comment: Update the answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: @code-mode, one small doubt. In MapsId annotation, "aId" and "bId" refers to the attributes of the class BKey right ? It may not be necessarily same as the actual column names of underlying table. To do that I have to add annotation Column(name = "a_id") and Column(name = "b_id") above those attributes in the class BKey I guess. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: You need to add column annotation if the column name and property name are different.

Answer (score 0):

**VM Users class**

```
public class VmUser implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID")
private Users user;
```

**Users class**

```
public class Users implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="user")
private VmUser vmUser;
```

**A class**

```
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable {

@Id
private long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="a")
private List<MyEntity> myEntitys;
```

**B Class**

```
@Entity
public class B implements Serializable {

@Id
private long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="b")
private List<MyEntity> myEntitys;
```

**MyEntity class**

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private MyEntityPK id;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID1")
private A a;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID2")
private B b;
```

**MyEntityPK class**

```
@Embeddable
public class MyEntityPK implements Serializable {

@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
private long id1;

@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
private long id2;
```